# Python code is not iterating through a list

Tags: python, loops

im attempting to create a code that takes an input word, finds its synonyms, and then goes through a pre established list of strings to find how may times the word and its synonyms occur. The code should then return results as a tuple like: [happy 12, joyous 4, excited 7, etc].

Ive made it this far, and i know the code is successfully finding synonyms but for some reason its not looping through the list of all the terms. its currently returning [joyous 1]. any thoughts on why its not looping?

```
class Entry:
   def  __init__(self, input_word, input_synonyms):
      self.word=input_word
      self.synonyms=input_synonyms

def search(keyword):
   for entry in Thesaurus:
      if keyword == entry.word:
         search_terms=[keyword]+entry.synonyms
   for word in search_terms:
      word_count= 0
      totals=[]
   for sentence in Corpus: 
      for corpus_word in sentence:
         if corpus_word == word:
            word_count+=1
            totals.append(word_count)   
   print (totals)
   return word, word_count

input = "happy" 
output = search(input) 
print(output)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please post your problem as [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is the `for sentence in Corpus` loop supposed to be nested inside the `for word in search_terms` loop?

Comment: 1/ Edit you indentation. 2/ What is class Entry used for. 3/ What are Thesaurus and corpus?

Comment: Apologies, in moving the code over i messed up the indent. I have them nested within each other. Thesaurus is pre-coded and provides synonyms for the entry, and the corpus is a large list of sentences.

Comment: Don't feel bad about formatting issues, they can be fixed. Just [edit] your post and you can fix it up. While you're at it, you may want to take the [tour] to learn more about how this site works, and read [ask] for guidance on asking questions that will be received well (and be likely to get answers).